# Query - Form Post Data lost after successful azure AD authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have two websites, one internal and the other hosted as Azure Website ( both leverages AAD for SSO)
Internal website redirects to Azure Website with Form Post Data. As Azure Website is AAD Authenticated, it redirects to login.microsoftonline.com, gets the token and comes back to Azure Website silently.
In the process of Auth, my form post data which was initially submitted is lost.
Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As your target website is protected by AAD, which allows OAuth 2.0 grand flow for authentication and authorization.

So, you can acquire an access token from Azure AD IDP, and set the access token in the form post request's `authorization` header, which will be verified by AAD and will not redirect to AAD SSO page to sign in. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code for more details about the basic work flow.

Furthermore, you can leverage Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries to help you to acquire the tokens. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries for all the library list.